# Makumba - set emptiness on a where clause

Tags: makumba

I'm wondering if there's a way to check for set emptiness in a mak:list's where clause.

I'd like to avoid having to mak:list the set in question just to mak:lastCount its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you can use subqueries in the WHERE condition.

Using the data definitions from http://www.makumba.org/page/DataModelHowto, i.e. company.Company with a set

```
suppliers = set company.Company
```

you can do something like

```
<mak:list from="company.Company c" where="(SELECT count(s) FROM c.suppliers s) > 0">
....
</mak:list>
```

You can also define this as a function in the MDD, e.g. as

```
hasSuppliers() { (SELECT count(s) FROM suppliers s) > 0 }
```

and then use it in your <mak:list> as

```
<mak:list from="general.Company c" WHERE="c.hasSuppliers()">
....
</mak:list>
```

Comment: Actually the above example will (in version 0.8.2.5 at least) cause an error. So the right approach would be to use `WHERE="(SELECT count(suppliers) FROM c.suppliers suppliers) >= 1"`. IN other words, do the comparison outside the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

hasSuppliers() can be defined simply as

```
hasSuppliers(){exists(FROM suppliers s)}
```